# disable next button after 1 click swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a doubt because the documentation is not very clear, I want to click on the next button on the right side and go back with the left button, because here in my code, it can go to the next one and come back with the next button I would like just 1 click to go to the side and the other button to go back my EXAMPLE:

I AM USING SWIPER TO DO THE ACT:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".slide-content", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 25,
  loop: true,
  centerSlide: 'true',
  fade: 'true',
  grabCursor: 'true',
  slidesPerGroup: 3,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    dynamicBullets: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next" ,
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },

  breakpoints:{
      0: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
      },
      520: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
      },
      950: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
      },
  },
});
```

```
                                      <div class="slide-container swiper">
                                            <div class="sldsss"> 

                                                <div class="imgg">
                                                <img src="/static/aaa/dr.png" alt="" class="card-img">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="slide-content">
                                                    <div class="card-wrapper swiper-wrapper">
                                                        
                                                      
                                                      
                                                      
                                                      
                                                      <div class="card swiper-slide">


                                                  




                                                            <div class="pscc">
                                                                
                                                              
                                                              <div id="cap1" class="card-image">
                                                                    <img src="/static/aaa/cp.png" alt="" class="card-img">
                                                                </div>
                                                             </div>


                                                            <video id="vdd1" class="vdd1" src="/static/aaa/videodr.mp4" controls>
                                                              <p>Seu navegador não suporta o vídeo. aqui está um <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O6lQZFBjgJsJELhmrM-I8R_cXiJWQFWx/view?usp=sharing">link para o video</a> instantâneo.</p>
                                                            </video>


                                                            <div onclick="ply1()" id="pl1" class="pl1">
                                                                <a href="##">
                                                                    <ion-icon class="pll1"  name="play-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>



                                                        </div>














                                                        <div class="card swiper-slide">
                                                            <div class="image-content">



                                                            <div id="cap2" class="card-image0">
                                                                    <img src="/static/aaa/cp2.png" alt="" class="card-img0">
                                                                    
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>



                                                            <video id="vdd2" class="vdd2" src="/static/aaa/vd2.mp4" controls>
                                                              <p>Seu navegador não suporta o vídeo. aqui está um <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EHusRbjEWghjTMwJgdm255aLDE2Eew-H/view?usp=share_link">link para o video</a> instantâneo.</p>
                                                            </video>





                                                            <div id="pl2" onclick="ply2()" class="pl2">
                                                                <a href="##">
                                                                    <ion-icon class="pll1"  name="play-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>

                                                        
                                                        </div>


















                                                        <div class="card swiper-slide">
                                                            <div class="image-content">

                                                                <div id="cap3" class="card-image1">
                                                                    <img src="/static/aaa/cp3.png" alt="" class="card-img1">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>



                                                            <video id="vdd3" class="vdd3" src="/static/aaa/vd3.mp4" controls>
                                                              <p>Seu navegador não suporta o vídeo. aqui está um <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OdQH_-yx76pusb4A9kNKkbLZ1WMCIFl-/view?usp=share_link">link para o video</a> instantâneo.</p>
                                                            </video>







                                                            <div id="pl3" onclick="ply3()" class="pl3">
                                                                <a href="##">
                                                                    <ion-icon class="pll1"  name="play-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>

                                                        



                                                        </div>






                                                        <div class="card swiper-slide">
                                                            <div class="image-content">

                                                                <div class="card-image2">
                                                                    <img src="/static/aaa/cp4.jpg" alt="" class="card-img2">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        
                                                        </div>







                                                        <div class="card swiper-slide">
                                                            <div class="image-content">

                                                                <div class="card-image3">
                                                                    <img src="/static/aaa/cp5.jpg" alt="" class="card-img3">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        
                                                        </div>









                                                        <div class="card swiper-slide">
                                                            <div class="image-content">

                                                                <div class="card-image4">
                                                                    <img src="/static/aaa/cp6.jpg" alt="" class="card-img4">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        
                                                        </div>




                                                    </div>
                                                </div>





                                                
                                                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-navBtn"></div>
                                                <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-navBtn"></div>
                                                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>






                                        </div>
                                      </div>
```

Comment: Can you  provide the html markup that was generated

Comment: I put a snippet of the html in the publication now, because it is quite large, there is no way to put everything here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, my friend, just disable the loop, so your next will no longer work, I believe that's it.

**  loop: false, **

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".slide-content", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 25,
  loop: false,
  centerSlide: 'true',
  fade: 'true',
  grabCursor: 'true',
  slidesPerGroup: 3,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    dynamicBullets: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next" ,
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },

  breakpoints:{
      0: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
      },
      520: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
      },
      950: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
      },
  },
});
```

Comment: WoW my friend it worked correctly, thank you very much that was it, I got it here thanks!